# mkfs.ntfs is not found, through the ntfs-3g package is installed

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to format a USB stick to NTFS file system with the `mkfs.ntfs` command and I get this in Terminal:

```
horbuli@BOSS:~$ sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ntfs-3g is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
horbuli@BOSS:~$ mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1
The program 'mkfs.ntfs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
horbuli@BOSS:~$
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Given answer didn't work for me but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31583596/3543808) worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Broken symlink:
The symlink to the mkfs.ntfs is wrong.

```
:~$ locate mkfs.ntfs /sbin/mkfs.ntfs
:~$ ls -l /sbin/mkfs.ntfs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Feb 25 15:52 /sbin/mkfs.ntfs -> /usr/sbin/mkntfs
:~$ ls -l /usr/sbin/mkntfs ls:
cannot access /usr/sbin/mkntfs: No such file or directory
```

Replace the old link with the /sbin/mkfs.ntfs -> /sbin/mkntfs then mkfs.ntfs will work.

Remove the current symlink:

```
sudo rm -f /sbin/mkfs.ntfs
```

Then create the correct link:

```
sudo ln -s /sbin/mkntfs /sbin/mkfs.ntfs
```

A bug has already been filed.

Comment: Note that for other operating systems like Centos 7, you need to install ntfsprogs to get mkfs.ntfs.

Comment: For my Debian I also had to run `sudo ln -s /sbin/mkntfs /usr/local/bin/mkntfs`